# __attribute__((weak)) function is'nt called even when there is no function overide it

Tags: c, attributes, weak

I have 3 files, they are main.c, Test.c, Test.h. This is what in inside those
main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include"Test.h"

int main()
{
   test_function();
   return 0;
}
```

Test.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include"Test.h"

void __attribute__((weak)) test_function()     
{
    printf("Test_fuction \n");
    getchar();
}
```

Test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H
#include<stdio.h>

void __attribute__((weak)) test_function();

#endif  // TEST_H
```

and this is my build process

```
gcc -c main.c -o main.o
gcc -c Test.c -o Test.o
gcc main.o Test.o -o main
```

from what i have learnt, the weak function would be used if user didn't redefine it. In my program i didn't redefine it, supposedly when the function is call in my main, it should print "Test_function" to the screen. But nothing happened when i run main.exe, the promt was opend then closed several seconds later. Could anybody tell me what i'm doing wrong here.
Thank you so much

Comment: It baically works as you describe. The problem is elsewhere (for exxample you do not compile the file you think you compile

Comment: Some Windows terminal emulators do not appear as terminals to the C library (i.e. `isatty(fileno(stdout))` is 0 when it should be 1), so the standard output stream and standard input stream end up being initialized to fully buffered mode instead of line buffered mode. Try adding calls`setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);` and `setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);` to `main()` before calling `test_function()`.

Comment: If you remove the `__attribute__((weak))` specifiers from the existing code, does it behave any differently? If it makes no difference then you should be looking elsewhere to explain the observed behavior.

Comment: after i remove __attribute__((weak)), it print "Test_function" as expected, also i have tried to add these 2 to my main() but it still does not work